# how to show tweets in list view in android?

Tags: android, twitter

i want to show tweets in a list view in android application.i have used following code but the tweets are not showing.. could anybody please tell how to show 5 latest tweets in list view which are reloaded after every 15 minutes? i have tried many codes but did not reached at any result!

```
 public class TweetsListActivity extends Activity {

        TextView tv;
        ListView lv;
        Twitter twitter;
        TextView username;
        TweetsListAdapter adapter;
        ArrayList<Tweet> tweetsDataList;
        String tweetsData;

        static ConfigurationBuilder cb;
        private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
        AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
        private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "";
        private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setContentView(R.layout.tweets_list);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            username =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            tweetsDataList = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
          String responseBody = null;
```

try {

```
  ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);              builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
URI website = new URI("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/.json");
 HttpClient hc =new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpGet get = new HttpGet();
get.setURI(website);
HttpResponse rp =  hc.execute(get);
HttpEntity entity = rp.getEntity();
 responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

if(((org.apache.http.HttpResponse)rp).getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
     String returned = null;
     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(returned);
    JSONArray ja = null;
     ja = json.getJSONArray("results");
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < ja.length(5); i1++) {
    JSONObject tweet_obj = ja.getJSONObject(i1);
    Tweet tweetsData = new Tweet();
    String username = tweet_obj.getString("from_user");
    String message = tweet_obj.getString("text");                                                               tweetsDataList.add(tweetsData);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
 Log.e("TwitterFeedActivity", "Error loading JSON", e);
            }
 adapter = new TweetsListAdapter(TweetsListActivity.this, tweetsDataList);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
  mSharedPreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
        }
    } 
   }          
      but no list is showing .. neither the logcat shows any error..
    i have used adapter classes. here is the link http://pastebin.com/XBErcu9c
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the internet permissin in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

For showing twitter feed, follow this tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxcfhAU2dDg&list=SP2F07DBCDCC01493A&index=147

Comment: yeah i am sure about this.. i have given internet permission

Comment: the above code gives error in logcat 

08-27 04:09:29.681: E/AndroidRuntime(4016): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twitter_demo_project/com.twitter_demo_project.TweetsListActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
08-27 04:09:29.681: E/AndroidRuntime(4016):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-27 04:09:29.681: E/AndroidRuntime(4016):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)

Comment: it gives problem regarding httpclient.. also that one is for version 1

Answer (score 0):

```
In view u haven't set the textview.So, Might this help you


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = convertView;
Holder holder=new Holder();

if (view == null) {
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = vi.inflate(R.layout.tweet_item, null);
}

Tweet tweet = tweets.get(position);
if (tweet != null) {
holder.username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listItem);
holder.message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);

if (username != null) {
username.setText(tweet.username);
}

if(message != null) {
message.setText(tweet.message);
}

}
view.setTag(holder);
return view;
}
}

class Holder{
TextView username;
TextView message;
}
```

Comment: it gives the same error in logcat regarding listview id.. please check the comment below .. i had pasted the logcat error

Comment: It's better to extend just activity.since ListActivity have it's own already defined list and you are trying to make inflate it with another listview,therefore it is showing error

Comment: now the error is this:
08-27 06:03:10.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4670): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 06:03:10.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4670): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twitter_demo_project/com.twitter_demo_project.TweetsListActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient cannot be cast to twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClient
08-27 06:03:10.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4670):  at com.twitter_demo_project.TweetsListActivity.getTweets(TweetsListActivity.java:186)

Comment: This might be looking problem in  connection code.So,prefer this link to form the connection:http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: can u please tell what is the problem in getTweets() method?

Comment: So,you can try in place of HttpClient make an object of DefaultHttpClient.IN one place you are using HttpGet and another place HttpPost.First,find in the link what is used

Comment: no need to do this.. actually i had imported org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient and twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClient but i must import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClient in place of that.. here  is the solution. thank you for help..

Comment: How you are passing the data from the previous activity.Provide me your statement

Comment: Send me your intent line where you are passing data

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(TwitterLoginActivity.this,
      TweetsListActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("tweetsdata",tweetsData);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

Comment: In which line you have used variable tweetsData

Comment: i have used it in TweetsListActivity.java and used this with intent in loginActivity

Answer (score 0):

One can Simply use "SearchTimeline" to show tweets in his/her android application : Please refer to the following link :

https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-timelines.html#timelines

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?